# How do you make a trigger in Linq to entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In linq to sql you make a "trigger" by making a partial class to the dbml file, and then inserting a partial method. Here is an example that wouldn't do anything because it calls the build-in deletion.

```
partial void DeleteMyTable(MyTable instance)
{
    //custom code here
    ExecuteDynamicDelete(instance);
    //or here :-)
}
```

But how do you do a "trigger" in linq to entities?

Comment: Linq is only for retrieving data, there is no equivalent of a database trigger in Linq. You could write some code that does something every time a particular entity is created/updated/deleted, however this has nothing to do with Linq.

Comment: I never talk about linq, I am mentioning two frameworks with the name "linq to sql" and "linq to entities", both frameworks deal with storing data. I would also be interested if it gets wrapped in an odata service or something. (As long as it is out-of-the-box).

Comment: The ORM framework is called Entity Framework, Linq to Entities is is just the Linq provider for Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at some overridable methods such as `SaveChanges` where you can tweak the entities before they reach the database.

here is an example straight from some code we have at the shop where we make sure that a `ReadOnlyContext` doesn't write anything to the DB:

```
public class ReadOnlyEntities : Entities
{
    public bool EnforceReadonlyBehavior { get; set; }


    public ReadOnlyEntities(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        EnforceReadonlyBehavior = true;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions options)
    {
        if (EnforceReadonlyBehavior)
        {
            if (
                ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added).Any()
                ||
                ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Modified).Any()
                ||
                ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Deleted).Any()
                )
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("nope");
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges(options);
    }
}
```

This lets you do lots of interesting things such as setting automatically some values (creation date / modification date). You can also catch the creation of the context in `OnContextCreated` where you can  setup all kind of specific behaviors.

There are also some partial methods on the entities themselves. Take a look at what is generated in the reference.cs file behind your edmx to find where you can hook some behaviors in your data access layer

As Ben Robinson points out though, this has nothing to do with linq, rather with the generated code in entity framework or linq to sql.

Comment: In this example it would be fairly hard to get the instance wouldn't it. Since SaveChanges can change a million different tables, and my plan was to do something that came close to a database trigger, but was in code. In my "linq to sql" example I did a delete trigger, but it also has for insert and edit.

Comment: Yeah, it's the highest possible level, but as I was saying there are some methods at the entities level that might help you, but you won't a 1-1 mapping of what was possible in Linq to SQL

Comment: ok, I guess that is the answer then. Then I'll just hook into the more specific code i have before the SaveChanges.